# Determining grammatical function of "after" and "before"

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

[*After* is defined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/after) as both a preposition and a conjunction, [as is *before*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/before).

In a sentence that uses *after* or *before*, how can one determine whether it is functioning as a preposition or a conjunction?

Take, for example, these sentences:

> 1. *Before/After* breakfast, Mac had a headache.
> 2. *Before/After* eating breakfast, Mac had a headache.
> 3. *Before/After* he ate breakfast, Mac had a headache.

What is the grammatical function of *before/after* in each of these sentences? **How did you determine whether *after/before* was a preposition or a conjunction?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are your examples with "before":

> Before **breakfast**, Mac had a headache.

Preposition. Reason: it takes a noun, *breakfast,* as its object. "Before breakfast" is a prepositional phrase, which functions as an adverb, modifying "Mac had a headache."

> Before **eating breakfast**, Mac had a headache.

Preposition. Reason: it introduces a prepositional phrase, ending in a noun, as in the previous sentence. "Eating" here is a gerund, serving as a noun. Notice that you could say "Eating breakfast **starts** your day off right." The verb in that sentence is *starts,* which is singular to agree with *eating,* the subject.

> Before **he ate breakfast**, Mac had a headache.

Conjunction. Reason: it introduces a whole clause that has its own subject. "He ate breakfast" could be a whole sentence. "Before" converts it into a subordinate clause.

Comment: @pyobum But contemporary grammars would say it *doesn't* alter the grammatical function: the clause is still the object of the preposition. In older English, in fact, well into the 17th century, such prepositions were routinely followed by the complementizer *that*, which marks what follows as a clause acting as a nominal. KJV, Matt 18:32: "Then his lord, after that he had called him, said unto him ..."

Comment: @pyobum Thanks! While I agree with StoneyB that these sorts of niceties are often not worth the bother, I think this one is worth distinguishing, because it explains people's expectations as they hear a sentence. If you hear "Before me...", your brain instantly gives up on the possibility that a subordinate clause is coming. The word "me", in the objective case, goes with a preposition but not a subordinating conjunction.  "Before he..." makes a listener expect a subordinate clause and _not_ a prepositional phrase.

Comment: But it is not a different use of the preposition which creates the expectation, it is the inflection on the pronoun. We do not assign the verb to one class with *I remember him helping* and another with *I remember he helped*; why should we treat prepositions differently?

Comment: @StoneyB As always, there's more complexity. But I think these concepts are useful for ordinary people to understand for talking about sentences in ordinary situations--like teaching the language or fixing up a sentence. In practice, the traditional concepts are simple and intuitive, and they explain the most important things to know about grammar, like opening up a prepositional phrase vs. opening up a clause (in this example). Contemporary grammar is surely superior for linguistics, but from what I've seen so far, it's overwhelming and not useful for everyday, non-scholarly talk.

Comment: Well, you get your simplification at the cost of complicating your terminology; and I suggest that you also lose the opportunity of emphasizing the critical matter of *licensing*, which we've seen come up over and over again here. I think, too, that our questioners are not well served by pedagogical techniques ('baby rules') suitable to primary and secondary school students; they're mostly adults, pretty sophisticated and literate, who are trying to master English for use in a university or grad school or professional setting.

Comment: ... But there's room for all sorts of approaches here. Indeed it is the particular strength of the SE format that questions get answers - *good* answers - suitable to every level of understanding and all sorts of needs.

Comment: @pyobum In this case that's wrong, really. It's very damaging to make learners distinguish between things that aren't significantly different in any way - escpecially when this means that learners don't understand why they are *THE SAME*. It means they won't understand the properties of the words they are talking about. Making students distinguish between the verb *know* when it takes a clause or a noun or is intransitive is a waste of learning time. Same is true of distinguishing whether a preposition is taking a finite clause, non-finite clause, noun or is intransitive. It's a waste ...

Comment: @pyobum .. of time. Worse is then giving the preposition a different label in each case: *Preposition, coordinating conjunction, adverb*. This isn't kind or enlightening. Intransitive prepositions have *nothing* to do with adverbs. Secondly you can see that the preposition/conjunction distinction is damaging to people's understanding of grammar. In "*after eating*", students are going to think eating is a noun because *after* is called a preposition here. It's not, it's a *VERB!*, 100%, pure and simple. It's not  not helpful, not educational and is misleading to keep up this distinction :(

Comment: Let me add that I think this is an excellent answer for people in a situation where the old-fashioned distinction is employed.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional grammar distinguished between different uses of words like *before* and *after*, calling them **a)** *prepositions* when they take phrases as their objects, and **b)** *subordinating conjunctions* when they introduce clauses. If you are taking tests, and your teacher makes the distinction, that is the basis for distinguishing them.

But there is no useful distinction here—the meaning doesn't change—so contemporary grammar calls them prepositions in both cases.

What you call the words doesn't matter at all, as long as you understand what they mean and how they mean it.

Comment: @pyobum The same way I explain that *while* can take a bare clause but not a *that* clause or a noun phrase, or that *want* takes marked infinitive clauses but not unmarked infinitive clauses or *that* clauses. Different words of the same class license different complements; that's just a fact of the language, and one that learners have to accept.

Comment: @pyobum How do you go about telling learners that different verbs take nouns, or interrogative clauses or predicative complements? I don't think it would help learners to split verbs into several new parts of speech to remember ;)

Comment: @pyobum In case you find it helpful, Oxford modern English grammar calls prepositions *conjunctive prepositions* when they take finite clauses :)

Comment: @pyobum Well you seem to want to split prepositions into different parts of speech because of what categories of word they take! Why not verbs too? At least that would be consistent! (I'm kind of joking - and kind of not. It's exactly why people realised that all prepositions were prepositions ...)

Comment: @pyobum Well, that's kind of the point, the grammar points to prepositions and subordinating conjunctions being the same part of speech, in the same way that the verb *know* is just a verb whether it takes a noun or a clause or nothing at all. These prepositions have the same syntactic function regardless of what comes after them. So it's exactly their context that demonstrates that prepositions are still prepositions, even if they aren't followed by a noun. But yes, we can agree to disagree :)

Comment: @pyobum I think this comes down to a question of whether you move from general distinctions to finer local distinctions or from local distinctions to more general distinctions.

Comment: I'd love to hear more about the pros and cons of traditional grammar vs. "contemporary" grammar as vocabularies for helping people learn English. This seems like a difficult venue for it, though. How about on meta? I'll post a question there right now. @Araucaria